Area Cross-Section of a dye / Trying to understand the interaction between photons and fluorophores

What is the right way to research / measure the cross-section of
fluorophores and compare this to excitation illumination to arrive at the probability of an interaction and hence an emission?

Consider a biological sample that is labelled with fluorophores.  Assume that we already know the number of sites to which a fluorophore can be bound.  Assume these are arranged on a surface and we can compute the number of molecules per square-micron.
Now we wish to illuminate this surface with a light source (e.g. LED, laser, ...).  Assume it is sufficiently monochromatic that we can consider it to be a single wavelength with a very narrow optical bandwidth.
We know the illumination irradiance (Watts/sq-cm).  We know the wavelength, so we can compute the photon flux (number of photons arriving per second / per square centimeter).
How is the probability of a photon interacting with a fluorophore defined?  I assume it is:
(cross-section of the fluorophore) x (photon flux) = number of interactions per second
Here's a common family of fluorophores:  Alexa Fluor - Wikipedia and a corresponding datasheet for Alexa 488 and FluorFinder
There's no mention of the area cross-section of these fluorophores

Is there a better way to describe / formulate this problem?
Is the area cross-section per molecule something that is application specific?
Does this value need to be measured by users or is it expected from the manufacturer?
Doesn't the measurement of quantum efficient need to take this into account?

